# IIS deployment Issue - my web app fails when clicking a function link. I get 'This localhost page can't be found'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have on my development machine (Windows 10 Pro) and the IIS Web Server installed.

I used VS 2017 to develop a .NET web application. It works fine when it is run in VS. The menu links find their correct action methods. It performs as expected.

I have a problem in IIS whereby I have published the .NET (.NET framework 4.8) web application.

The publish to IIS created the folder on my C drive: inetpub\wwwroot\ProfileAndOrBlog.

[image]

I launch the web app in the browser with this URL: http://localhost/ProfileAndOrBlog.

I then sign into the web app using a top menu item **just fine**. That menu link is coded in the view as:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "SignIn", "SignIn", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signinBtn", @class = "btn btn-primary my-signin-btn" })</li>
```

The URL generated is: http://localhost/ProfileAndOrBlog/SignIn/SignIn

After sign in, I get this page.

The URL generated is: http://localhost/ProfileAndOrBlog/User

[image]

I can now click on any side bar menu (a function of the app) - a link.

When I use the side bar menu link 'Make Suggestions' coded in the view as:

```
<a href="/UserSuggestionMaint/Index"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Make Suggestions</a>
```

I get a 'This localhost page can't be found'.

[image]

The URL generated is: http://localhost/UserSuggestionMaint/Index.

It does not have the ProfileAndOrBlog/ as part of the route.

Note: if I manually add in the missing part of the route to the URL, it works.

http://localhost/ProfileAndOrBlog/UserSuggestionMaint/Index

**So, why is that route part missing?**

Comment: just add "~" char before each address in the href attrubute: <a href="~/UserSuggestionMaint/Index"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Make Suggestions</a>

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question but it seems your problem is simply about routes.

When using links

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "SignIn", "SignIn", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signinBtn", @class = "btn btn-primary my-signin-btn" })</li>
```

Simply means it should display "Sign In" on a button and the link will be mapped to something like below:
"/SignIn/SignIn"
and
"/UserSuggestionMaint/Index"

In simple terms routes are usually "/Controller/action" in MVC.

So make sure you are referencing the right action method and it will work.

Using "/UserSuggestionMaint/Index" means the controller should be something like UserSuggestionMaintController and the Index action which will render the Index View.

Comment: The web app works fine for all the side bar menu links when I run it in VS 2017. I am referencing the correct action methods as proven when I run it in VS. The sign in menu item (defined differently than the side bar menus) works fine in VS as well when running the app via the URL (produced by the publish to IIS). I understand routes. But I get that error message when I click on any of the side bar menu links as noted in the <a> tag above. It's as though it is not resolving the path correctly.

Comment: Give the name of the controller as well as the action method you want to navigate to let me give you a valid link to it. Because you are not being definite.

Comment: As stated above, I use <a href="/UserSuggestionMaint/Index"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Make Suggestions</a> where UserSuggestionMaint is the controller name and Index is the action name.

Comment: use <a href="~/UserSuggestionMaint/Index"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Make Suggestions</a>

Answer (score 0):

Something you need to know about using absolute and relative paths in hyperlink `<a href>`,

- Beginning with http:// or //. The browser will resolve the link as an
  absolute URL.
- Beginning with a single /. The browser will resolve the link as
  relative to the domain.
- Beginning with text. The browser will resolve the link as relative to
  the page.
- Beginning with #. The browser will look for an HTML element on the
  same page (by ID) and scroll to it if found.

So when you use `<a href="/UserSuggestionMaint/Index">`, it adds this content after domian not current url.

But when you use `@Html.ActionLink`, it returns a specified link text according to an anchor element.

In my test, I use `@Html.ActionLink` in layout page. When I set the MVC application as a separate site, `@Html.ActionLink` generates a hyperlink likes this:

[image]

If I set the MVC applciation as a sub application under a site, it likes this:
[image]

Part of `/ProfileAndOrBlog` url is necessary so that IIS can know which application you want to access. Then asp.net route can know `UserSuggestionMaint` is controller and `index` is action.

### The solution is:

1. Not use relative URL of hyperlink but absolute URL. `<a href="http://domain name/ProfileAndOrBlog/UserSuggestionMaint/Index">`.
2. Deploy the mvc application as a separate site not a sub application under default web site.
3. Not use  but `@Html.ActionLink` to dynamically generate a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the insight.

To not change each of the href's to add in the tilde to the beginning of the path as suggested, I instead changed my Publish Profile. I had 'ProfileAndOrBlog' as part of the **Site name** (Default Web Site/ProfileAndOrBlog) and the **Destination** URL (http://localhost/ProfileAndOrBlog). I removed it in both places and it resolved the URL problem. Here is how my Publish Profile is now:

[image]

I now can successfully access all the functions of my web app when I launch the web site in the browser with this URL: http://localhost

So for my 'Make Suggestions' link, the URL is now: http://localhost/UserSuggestionMaint/Index.